# "Working" or "will be working"?

Tags: tense, verbs, grammaticality-in-context, future-tense

In the context: `Ms. Johnson will be tired tonight due to the fact that she is busy with her work all day long.` Is there any other way to say it correctly?

For example:

> A) Ms. Johnson will be tired tonight as she will be working all day long.

or

> B) Ms. Johnson will be tired tonight as she is working all day long.

I would choose the option "B" but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to express this idea correctly. All three of your examples are grammatically correct. If you are asking which is the best way to construct this sentence, you are really seeking opinions rather than guidance on grammar.

However, there are a few things to bear in mind. One is: don't use more words than are necessary to say what you want. Brevity is best. Another is to take the context into consideration.

The expression **due to the fact that** takes five words to say **because** or **as**.  So avoid the expression where you can. It's pompous.

Also, **all day** means the same in this context as **all day long**. So you could omit **long** without changing the meaning unless you have a particular reason to include it.

If you were speaking first thing in the morning, when the day stretches ahead, you might say:

> Ms. Johnson will be tired tonight as she **will be** working all day.

If you were speaking later, you might prefer:

> Ms. Johnson will be tired tonight as she **is** working all day.

But both are correct and this is really just a matter of choice. Neither is better than the other.

Generally speaking, this site will not give you guidance on *good* writing as opposed to *correct grammar*. So it's always a good idea to say why you are in doubt about something and how you have tried to resolve it yourself.

Comment: In your last paraphrase I think you forgot to delete *be*.